# How to refer to pivot table column after GROUPBY?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

How to refer to pivot table column **num** after GROUPBY?

DF after group by:
[image]

Comment: your question is not clear. what does the exact meaning of `refer`? what do you want to do after referring?

Comment: Do you need `df.index` Or `df.reset_index()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your num column is an index of the dataframe. If you need to refer to a row by the value in the 'num' column, you can use df.loc[value]. If you want to get the values in 'num' themselves, you can access them from df.index